# How to pass parameter to a laravel elequent model's event observer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, model

I have a model in laravel and I want to do something after the first time which an object of my model is created. the simplest way is to add a static boot method inside my model's class like the code below:

```
class modelName extends Model
{
      public static function boot()
      {
         parent::boot();

         self::created(function ($model) {
             //the model created for the first time and saved
             //do something
            //code here
         });
     }
}
```

so far so good! the problem is: the ONLY parameter that created method accepts is the model object itself(according to the documentation) :

> Each of these methods receives the model as their only argument.
>
> https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events

I need more arguments to work with after model creation. how can I do that?

Or is there any other way to do something while it's guaranteed that the model has been created?

laravel version is 5.5.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved the issue using static property in eloquent model class:

```
class modelName extends Model
{
  public static $extraArguments;
  public function __construct(array $attributes = [],$data = [])
  {
     parent::__construct($attributes);
     self::$extraArguments = $data  ; 

  public static function boot()
  {
     parent::boot();

     self::created(function ($model) {
         //the model created for the first time and saved
         //do something
        //code here
         self::$extraArguments; // is available in here
     });
   }
}
```

It works! but I don't know if it may cause any other misbehavior in the application.

Using laravel events is also a better and cleaner way to do that in SOME cases.but the problem with event solution is you can't know if the model has been created for sure and it's time to call the event or it's still in creating status ( and not created status).

Comment: What do you mean if it is in created status? This is not how Laravel works.

Comment: This is bad code and does not follow best practices.

Comment: @plushyObject It means the moment that you are definitely sure that the model object has been created and saved in database and it's exactly the way that laravel works. there's a delay for saving in database Ex: it you write $model->save(); and then $this->do_something_method() , in the method called right after the "save" line you can't and shouldn't suppose that the model has been saved in database because of the delay for saving

Comment: your solution can not solve the problem that I mentioned in the comment above@plushyObject  you will realize such problems when the load of database server increases and the latency time rises!

Comment: If you run Model::create(), there is no delay when creating that object, dude.

Comment: For anyone that comes here and reads this, I would not implement this and would implement the code I provide in my answer leveraging the tools built into Laravel and not hacking it to pieces.

Comment: "the difference between save and create is that save accepts a full Eloquent model instance while create accepts a plain PHP array" it's the only difference between save and create according to documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method regards of fillable attribute in model's class.

Answer (score -1):

You're close. What I would probably do would be to dispatch an event right after you actually create the model in your controller. Something like this.

```
class WhateverController
{
    public function create()
    {
        $model = Whatever::create($request->all());
        $anotherModel = Another::findOrFail($request->another_id);

        if (!$model) {
            // The model was not created.
            return response()->json(null, 500);
        }

        event(new WhateverEvent($model, $anotherModel));
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is it can't figure it out if the model has been created for sure or it's still in creating status. so it may cause some major bugs in your code.

Comment: @blank94 Just run a check to make sure the model exists... This is a scripting language.